# Conditional logic in the definition of ordered field

Tags: real-analysis

In Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", he defines an *ordered field* as *field* $F$ which is also an *ordered set*, such that:

1. $x + y < x + z$ if $x$, $y$, $z$ $\in$ F and $y < z$,
2. $xy > 0$ if $x \in F$, $y \in F$, $x > 0$, and $y > 0$.

I'm confused about the second condition. Its contrapositive is:

$xy \le 0$ if one of the following is true:

1. $x \le 0$, $y \le 0$
2. $x \le 0$, $y \ge 0$
3. $x \ge 0$, $y \le 0$

However, #1 is false. Can you help me find a flaw in my reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contrapositive of$$x>0\wedge y>0\implies xy>0$$is$$xy\leqslant0\implies x\leqslant0\vee y\leqslant0.$$

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive of "if x>0 and y> 0 then xy> 0" is
"if $xy\le 0$ then either $x\le 0$ or $y\le 0$."

Your mistake is treating that as if it were "if and only if" rather than just "if".  The fact that BOTH x and y negative gives xy positive does NOT contradict that statement.